# Склонение названий рек

Tags: склонение, топонимика

В моей местности протекают две реки: Западная Чусовая и Полдневая Чусовая. Как правильно написать: "около рек Полдневой и Западной Чусовых" или "около рек Полдневой и Западной Чусовой"? "Междуречье Большой и Малой Нязь" или "междуречье Большой и Малой Нязи"? В одной старой книге (1905 г.) я встречал первое написание, в других, более современных, - второе. Какой же вариант верный?

Answer (score 1):

«Около рек Полдневой Чусовой и Западной Чусовой».

Вики пишет:

> Географические названия склоняются
>
> 1. В сочетании со словом *город* названия *склоняются независимо от их рода: из города Самары, в городе Москве*. Вариант *в городе Москва* не
>    соответствует литературной норме. Правильно: *в городе Москве* (не *в
>    городе Москва*), *в городе Санкт-Петербурге, у города Ишимбая* (не *у
>    города Ишимбай*), *из города Киева, над городом Парижем*;
> 2. В сочетании с другими обобщающими словами, род которых совпадает с родом названия: *в деревню Петровку, под хутором Михайловским, в селе
>    Красном, на острове Валааме, на берегу реки Волги, на Зелёном мысе* (не
>    *на мысе Зелёный*), *долина Сухого ручья* (не *долина ручья Сухой*), *на
>    Русском острове* (не *на острове Русский*).
>
> https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5

А тут род как раз совпадает, так что эти названия рек склоняются: «на реке Полдневой Чусовой», «на реке Западной Чусовой». Но нужно, чтобы и неместный житель смог без труда разобраться, что река — Полдневая Чусовая, а не просто Полдневая и тем более не Чусовых.

Answer (score 1):

Около рек Полдневой Чусовой и Западной Чусовой.

Совпадающее слово **не выносится** из названий, как в математике множитель за скобки:
*(Полдневой и Западной) Чусовых*

Answer (score 0):

Можно обратить внимание на то, что  при объединении названий  слово «реки» обычно не используется, так что можно предложить **два варианта:**

(1) около рек  Западной Чусовой и Полдневой Чусовой,

(2) около Западной и Полдневой Чусовой.

Примеры

Чусовая если и не наиглавнейшая река Урала, то, безусловно, самая красивая. Образуется она в семидесяти пяти километрах южнее Свердловска слиянием **Западной и Полдневой Чусовой…**

От слияния **двух рек Полдневой Чусовой и Западной Чусовой** образовалось единое русло реки Чусовой…

Другой пример: Пешком через Большую и Малую Невку (экскурсия).

Comment: Спасибо! Только не Полдневной, а Полдневой

Comment: Да?  Но я же копировала текст, значит, у них неправильно?

Comment: *двух рек Полдневой Чусовой и Западной Чусовой* — похоже на ситуацию с Яковом, а то и хуже.

Comment: Вопрос решён. Здесь по аналогии: от слияния рек Северной и Полдневой Сысерти (а не Сысертей) образуется река Сысерть и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.  А кто решил? Мне такая запись не очень нравится.. Могу объяснить почему. Здесь конфликт мн. числа (рек) и единственного числа (Сысерти). На слух воспринимается плохо, правила предлагают нам избегать этого в любой ситуации. Давайте  еще послушаем: пешком через реки Большую и Малую Невку. Хорошо звучит? Чем ближе эти формы, тем хуже.

Comment: Вот ответ на этот вопрос с сайта russkiiyazyk.ru: "В составных названиях рек «Полдневая Чусовая» и «Западная Чусовая», если объединить вторую часть, используем форму единственного числа:
около рек Полдневой и Западной Чусовой.
Слово «Нязь» имеет форму женского рода. В современном русском языке такие слова склоняются:
междуречье Большой и Малой Нязи". Мне всё ясно. Я пишу книгу, связанную с географическими названиями своей родины. Поэтому этот вопрос был важен, так как в книгах пишется по-разному

Comment: Никто не спорит с тем, что здесь должно быть ед. число (Чусовой) – разумеется, да.  Слово реки желательно убрать, если вы объединяете названия.

Comment: понял. А в случае с горами действует такое же правило? Например, "пешком через горы Большую и Малую Рассольную".

Comment: Да, здесь конфликт даже еще больше ощущается: горы – Большую.  Надо как-то корректировать текст так, чтобы избегать такие ситуации.

Comment: «Пешком через Большую (Рассольную?) и Малую Рассольную гору»?

Comment: Попробуйте пройти пешком, но я бы не рискнула.  :)  А написала бы я так (зависит от контекста):  Пешком через Большую и Малую Рассольную (соединение названий). Или: Пешком через горы Большую Рассольную и  Малую Рассольную (нет соединения названий).

Comment: «Пешком через Рассольные горы — Большую и Малую». (Я совсем не шучу: мне бы понравилось.)

Comment: Пожалуй, нет, здесь даже тире не поможет – падеж не тот. Можно сказать так:  Есть две Рассольные горы –  Большая и Малая.